# How to let a number grow by 1 n times

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to let a number gow by one, for n times. This is what I have so far:

```py
import itertools
N = 3
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, N):
    number = 0
    number = number + 1
    print(number)
```

This works, but the problem with this is, that the number is always 1. When I try to assign number outside of the repetition, I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

The whole code is a bit bigger. That might be the problem.

Edit:

```py
with open('./json/accounts.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

number_of_types = len(data)
N = number_of_types
print(number_of_types)

embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Current stock",
    color=discord.Colour.from_rgb(0,255,0)
    )
embed.add_field(name=list(data.keys())[0], value='test')
number = 0
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, N):
    number = number + 1
    print(number)
    embed.add_field(name=list(data.keys())[number], value="test")
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is the whole code and when running it, I get the Error `IndexError: list index out of range` in my CMD.

This is the json file:

```py
{
    "Crunchyroll": [
        {
            "test123:test123": "1",
            "test321:test321": "2"
        }
    ],

    "Netflix": [
        {
            "test123:test123": "1",
            "test321:test321": "2"
        }
    ],

    "Disney": [
        {
            "test123:test123": "1",
            "test321:test321": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have the `number = 0` in the loop, which makes the value of it 0 for each step. Also, instead of `itertools.repeat(None, N):`, you may use `range(N)`.

Comment: item=1 print([item+i for i in range(N)]) ?? # will print 1,2,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can easily do this without itertools ->

Let's say the number is n = 10 and you wanna grow it t=3 times

```
n=10
t=3
result = [n+i for i in range(3)]
# [10,11,12]
```

With itertools using enumerate ->

```
import itertools
t = 3
n=10
for number, _ in enumerate(itertools.repeat(None, N), start=n):
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are declaring variable inside the loop, `variable is assigned to 0 on every loop`

Please declare the variable outside.

```py
import itertools
N = 3
number = 0
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, N):
    number = number + 1
    print(number)
```

Comment: I already tried this. When assigning the number outside the loop, I get the error I mentioned.

Comment: You can use enumerate - >import itertools
N = 3
for number, _ in enumerate(itertools.repeat(None, N), start=1):
    print(number)

Comment: @EckigerLuca: I dont see any list being used in the code. Please paste the complete code in the original question.

Comment: I tested it, and working fine. I hope you are having some more logics along with this code in your requirement. could you share that?